# Phonegap 2.0.0 - 2.1.0 Facebook integration

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm pretty new in Phonegap, but I already have an app in place. I would like it to connect to Facebook, but I can't find any solutions for Phonegap 2.0.0 or Phonegap 2.1.0. Could anyone point to to the right direction where I could begin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was use following plugin, and it works fine:

https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Comment: To be clear, are you using this plugin with PhoneGap 2.1, or PhoneGap 2.0?

Comment: The above like is not active any longer.

Answer (score 1):

I am also using plugin from GIT for PhoneGap 2.1 [Facebook-plugin-integration-for-PhoneGap-2.1](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Facebook-plugin-integration-for-PhoneGap-2.1-for-iOS-and-Android)

Comment: you should post this on a comment. This does not provide new info to the question

Comment: am new here.. will take care next time