# Facebook Integration with iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios6, facebook-login

I am working on application where I want to add functionality of "**Login with Facebook**". As per the facebook documentation, they have provided facebook SDK and social/AdSupport/Account Frameworks. I tried sample application on facebook but its not giving what I exactly want, How do I achieve following things which should be compatible for both iOS 5 and iOS 6 devices.

**Facebook Sample:**
1. Tap on login button takes user to safari browser for login authentication.
2. After login user return back to our application.
3. After logout from session if user again try to login he/she will not ask for username password, the SDK direct take them to Facebook page with "Okay" button. After tap on Okay button it retursn them to our application.

**My Requirements:**
1. Tap on login button should display login dialog there itself, instead to takes user to the safari browser.
2. After Login, the login dialog should disappear and user should display application home screen.
3. After logout from session if user try to relogin again, then it should display login dialog.

What I noticed that because of stored cookies in safari browser user is not asked for re-login again.

So, if anybody has an idea then help me to fulfill above requirement? or How do I achieve the above things?

Comment: Please  check :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673729/phonegap-2-0-0-2-1-0-facebook-integration/

Comment: try this one: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Twitter_and_Facebook_into_iPhone_iOS_6_Applications

Comment: I have already gone through the above one, it's not what I am trying to achieve. I want login functionality.

Answer (score 3):

in ios 6 you can use `SLComposerview` function which is available in Social Framework where as for ios 5 and lower versions, you have to use the facebook sdk which is available here https://developers.facebook.com/ios/

You can read the instruction and try running samples first which will give you a better idea.

Good Luck!